# Команда выдачи роли абсолютно всем участникам сервера

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Помогаю другу оформить и руководить его сервером. Мне необходимо написать команду, которая бы выдавала определенную роль всем участникам сервера в дискорд. Я полез с этим вопросом в документацию, но вообще ничего не понял. Решил обратится за помощью сюда.

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, jsonify
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from config import settings

api_key = "buba"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx): 
    author = ctx.message.author 
    await ctx.send(f'Hello, {author.mention}!') 

@bot.command()
async def pat(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animu/pat') 
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) 
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x1f3151, title = 'Random pat') 
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link']) 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed) 

@bot.command()
async def hug(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animu/hug') 
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) 

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x1f3151, title = 'Random hug') 
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link'])  
    await ctx.send(embed = embed) 

@bot.command()
async def wink(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/animu/wink') 
    json_data = json.loads(response.text) 

    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0x1f3151, title = 'Random wink') 
    embed.set_image(url = json_data['link']) 
    await ctx.send(embed = embed) 

@bot.command()
async def weather(ctx, *, city: str):
    city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    channel = ctx.message.channel

    if x["cod"] != "404":
        async with channel.typing():
              y = x["main"]
        current_temperature = y["temp"]
        current_temperature_celsiuis = str(round(current_temperature - 273.15))
        current_pressure = y["pressure"]
        current_humidity = y["humidity"]
        z = x["weather"]
        weather_description = z[0]["description"]
        weather_description = z[0]["description"]
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Погода в городе: {city_name}",
                              color=ctx.guild.me.top_role.color,
                              timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,)
        embed.add_field(name="Статус:", value=f"**{weather_description}**", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Температура(C)", value=f"**{current_temperature_celsiuis}°C**", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Влажность(%)", value=f"**{current_humidity}%**", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Давление(hPa)", value=f"**{current_pressure}hPa**", inline=False)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.ibb.co/CMrsxdX/weather.png")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Запрошено {ctx.author.name}")
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await channel.send("Ты где живешь, еба*лак?")

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Comment: ну, для начала покажите хоть то,  как вы вообще запустили бота. Т. е. просто залогнились в его аккаунт с помощью токена через **Python**.  Просто это даст нам понять, что вы хотя-бы прочитали, как запустить бота, и создали вы его через Discord Developers Portal вообще. Дальше мы уже вам поможем.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def add_role(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

!add_role @role